# How to align to center font awesome icons

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I want to align center the font awesome icons with a lower text section, but I'm unable to get the results

This is the html piece:

```css
.education-title {
    font-family: Alef, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-family: Alef, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.edu-container {
    padding-top:50px;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    list-style: none;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    margin:auto;
    background-color: white;
    font-family: Alef, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.edu-text {
    text-align: center;
}

.edu-sub-text {
    text-align: left;
    
}

li > i {
    font-size: 100px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
<ul class="edu-container">
   <h2 class="education-title">EDUCATION</h2>
   <li>
      <i id="icon" class="fas fa-laptop-code"></i>
      <h2 class="edu-text">Degree</h2>
      <p class="edu-sub-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident aspernatur non animi maiores et magnam repellat tenetur tempora. Voluptatibus perspiciatis obcaecati odio sint vel et id maiores optio fugit rerum?</p>
   </li>
   <li>
      <i id="icon" class="fab fa-free-code-camp"></i>
      <h2 class="edu-text">Degree</h2>
      <p class="edu-sub-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident aspernatur non animi maiores et magnam repellat tenetur tempora. Voluptatibus perspiciatis obcaecati odio sint vel et id maiores optio fugit rerum?</p>
   </li>
   <li>
      <i id="icon" class="fas fa-university"></i>
      <h2 class="edu-text">Degree</h2>
      <p class="edu-sub-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident aspernatur non animi maiores et magnam repellat tenetur tempora. Voluptatibus perspiciatis obcaecati odio sint vel et id maiores optio fugit rerum?</p>
   </li>
   <li>
      <i id="icon" class="fas fa-laptop-code"></i>
      <h2 class="edu-text">Degree</h2>
      <p class="edu-sub-text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident aspernatur non animi maiores et magnam repellat tenetur tempora. Voluptatibus perspiciatis obcaecati odio sint vel et id maiores optio fugit rerum?</p>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to have the icons aligned center like the "degree" word is, to make it look nice, but I've tried everything i had on mind and none worked. A little help for this code padawan would be really apreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you explicitly set text-align: left on the p tags then it would be suitable to simply add

```
.edu-container > li {
    text-align: center;
}
```

You can't call text-align: center on the I tag because it is inline.

Cheers

Comment: You're welcome.  The trick with text-align is that it won't change the alignment of an element, but it will change the alignment of it's contents (text or inline elements).

Answer (score 0):

Put the icon tag between the center tag like:

```
<center>
    <i id="icon" class="fas fa-university"></i>
</center>
```